# How to update multiple divs only when new changes is detected jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I want to be updating the divs with posts comments only when new comment is added to MySQL database.

Each of the div have a unique id for posts.

Here what i have but this only update one div leaving the rest empty

Any help is appreciated.

I have 3 php files

Bed.php (index page).

Bed2.php (display last comment time, if changes update with new data from bed1.php)

Bed1.php (post comment from data base for each post id)

```
    <div class="commcommmpost1" idss="1" id="gantt1">comment from post with id 1</div>
<div class="commcommmpost1" idss="2" id="gantt2">comment from post with id 2</div>
<div class="commcommmpost1" idss="3" id="gantt3">comment from post with id 3</div>
<div class="commcommmpost1" idss="4" id="gantt4">comment from post with id 4</div>



<script>
$i = "1";
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
$('.commcommmpost1').each(function(index,
      el) {
   var thisIDs = $(this).attr('idss');
    $.get("bed2.php?id=" +thisIDs, function(data) {
        //condition of data
        if (data != $i) {
            $('#gantt' +thisIDs).load('bed1.php?id=' +thisIDs).fadeIn("slow");
           // alert(thisIDs);

            $i = data;
        }
    });
   });
}, 2000);

</script>
```

Comment: Your `$i` is global, so this will be the same for all your elements. But you are comparing it to the individual data `bed2.php` returned for a specific ID - can't see that making much sense.

Comment: @CBroe any solution to make it work is appreciated.  I tried this which work but  it keeps updating even data didn't change.

Comment: It doesn't make too much sense, to make _two_ requests each to begin with. It doesn't even make too much sense, to have a _separate_ request for each of those elements. Your script should rather gather the relevant IDs and last modification times from your existing HTML output, send that data to the server in _one_ request - and have it respond with a JSON data structure, that contains the new data to insert into each element - or the info, that there was no new data.

Comment: <script>
$('.commcommmpost1').each(function(i) {
        var thisIDs = $(this).attr('idss');
        $i = thisIDs;
        alert($i);
setInterval(function() {
    $.get("bed2.php?id=" +thisIDs, function(data) {
        //condition of data
        if (data != $i) {
            $('#gantt' +thisIDs).load('bed1.php?id=' +thisIDs).fadeIn("slow");
            alert(thisIDs);

            $i = data;
        }
    });

}, 2000);
   });
</script>

Comment: @CBroe a sample example of  this is appreciated because my divs are added dynamic with ajax load more